# Issue when hiding the status bar in landscape mode iphone

Tags: iphone, hide, landscape, statusbar, uiapplication

In my iPhone application, the default orientation throughout the app is Landscape mode. I wanted to hide the status bar, so I used `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];` in the appDelegate. But the status bar is hidden only in the first splash screen, and in the view controller it leaves a white space in the top and in the all other view controllers it is leaving a white space in the bottom. I used following methods to solve the issue, but didn't work.

1. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];`
2. In the info.plist Status bar is initially `hidden = YES`
3. Set the status bar is equal to `None` in the interface builder.
4. Added `[self.view setNeedsLayout];`
    `[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];`

Still its not fixed. Any idea? Please help.

Comment: I tried using [application setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone] and for me it is working fine.How are you assigning view controller frame?

Comment: i am not assigning the frame through code, i have added the views to the view in the interface builder file.

Comment: did you remove status bar from the xib? may be `setStatusBarHidden:YES` function just called for portrait mode, try that for all orientation mode, i dont have any other idea about this.

Comment: i tried that too, still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, to hide the status bar `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];` is enough. But still there was a white space. As I was added the views to the view controllers through Interface Builder, the frame size of each views not getting adjusted automatically when the status bar got hidden. So, I had to set the Autoresizing directions in the Size Inspector in Interface Builder for each views. That fixed the issue. Hope it will be helpful for some one, thats why I am posting the answer here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your .plist file and add a new key "Status bar is initially hidden" then set a value as YES. I hope that helps you.